# How to update specific data inside a column based on a pattern with SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, pattern-matching

For some reasons, in my database, in a table column, I have some data with an absolute url like this :

```
+---------------------------------+
|               url               |
+---------------------------------+
| /foo/12                         |
| http://www.myexample.com/foo/13 |
| http://www.myexample.com/foo/14 |
+---------------------------------+
```

I would like to update absolute url as relative url like this :

```
+---------------------------------+
|               url               |
+---------------------------------+
| /foo/12                         |
| /foo/13                         |
| /foo/14                         |
+---------------------------------+
```

How can I do this with a SQL query ?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `REPLACE(str,from_str,to_str)`

Returns the string str with all occurrences of the string from_str replaced by the string to_str. REPLACE() performs a case-sensitive match when searching for from_str.

So you can write replace(url,'http://www.myexample.com','') in an update query

```
update table_name set url = replace(url,'http://www.myexample.com','') where 1=1
```

Comment: What means `where 1=1` ?

Comment: it's optional, to force update of all rows, like when we say update table where true